# Can a teenage runaway get refugee status or migrate?

Tags: immigration, usa, refugees

If a teenager runs away because they have an emergency, for example, their parents are threatening to kill them, would the US Embassy in the UAE help them migrate?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not a US citizen, it is unlikely that the United States would interfere with parental or custody decisions made by other governments. As you are in the United Arab Emirates, it does have resources that may be able to help.

> [**Children's rights**](https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/social-affairs/children)
>
> Federal Law No. 3 of 2016 concerning child rights, also known as Wadeema's Law, stresses that all children must be provided with appropriate living standards, access to health services, education, equal opportunities in essential services and facilities without any kind of discrimination. ***The law protects children against all forms of negligence, exploitation, physical and psychological abuses.***
>
> The law allows childcare specialists to remove children from their homes against parents' wishes and without judicial permission in cases of imminent danger. In less severe cases, specialists may intervene by visiting the child regularly, providing social services and mediating a solution between the family and the child.
>
> Those who put children in danger, abandon them, neglect them, leave them without supervision, do not enroll them in school or register them upon their birth will be subject to a prison sentence or a fine. The law applies to all children up to the age of 18.
>
> **[Children's Safety](https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/justice-safety-and-the-law/children-safety/childrenssafety)**
>
> **Hotlines**
>
> Schoolchildren can use the hotline number 80051115 to communicate directly with Ministry of Education regarding any issue that may affect their learning process. Education specialists supervise the hotline.

The [UAE Ministry of the Interior Child Protection Centre](http://www.moi-cpc.ae/en/Default.aspx) does investigate allegations of abuse, both physical and emotional, and neglect. If you feel you are in imminent danger, you might confide in a trusted adult, such as a teacher at your school and, perhaps, ask them to go with you to the authorities.